# Ensure data doesn't cross page boundary

Tags: 6502, ca65

I'm trying to create a switch statement as below, which works well until something crosses a page. The switch destination is auto generated, which is why its in another file. 'structure, x' holds the offset (the case switch). In the case below, it will be either $00, $02, $04 or $06.

Is there anyway to ensure that the returnAddr isn't at $xx00? (Does that actually matter here?) And that the switchlist doesn't cross a boundary?

```
    lda #>returnAddr
    pha
    lda #<returnAddr-1
    pha

    ; store where we want to go
    lda switchlist+1
    pha
    lda switchlist
    clc
    adc structure, x
    pha

    rts ; make call to the proc in the switchlist

returnAddr:
    ; ...
    rts
```

and in another file I have (where case_x are function labels)

```
switchlist:
    .word case_1
    .word case_2
    .word case_3
    .word case_4
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear how all this hangs together, but my guess is "adc structure, x" happens but if there's a carry out you don't modify the high byte, because "lda switchlist+1" has already been pushed.

Comment: @NickWestgate precisely, which is fine if the switchlist is in one 256 byte block. That's what I'm trying to ensure.

Comment: And what is supposed to happen if there are more cases than can fit in one page?

Comment: If you just want switchlist to page aligned, use the .align directive: https://www.cc65.org/doc/ca65-11.html#ss11.4

Comment: Which assembler are you using? You could probably use some kind of assertion. Or a macro. Or adjust your code generation to bail out if it doesn't fit in a page. Anyway, your question is too vague to answer as it stands

Comment: Most assemblers have an ```org``` or ```align``` directive, depends on which assembler you're using

Answer (score 0):

I was always taught to structure it like this:

```
LDA #2   ;say we want case_3
ASL      
TAX
JSR handleSwitch  ;pushes the return address for us.
;return here after we goto the desired case.
```

```
handleSwitch:
LDA switchlist+1,x
pha
LDA switchlist
pha
rts  ;"return" to desired case

case_1:
rts  ;each of these returns to after "jsr handleSwitch"
case_2:
rts
case_3:
rts
case_4:
rts
```

The key here is that you `JSR` to your trampoline, inlining it won't have the desired effect. If you build it this way it doesn't matter if your return address crosses a page boundary.